# How to fill available space without changing Column Layout

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I have a textfield and a button on the same row.
I would like the textfield to take up all available space, and the button to only take up space in relation to the text on the button.

Visually I can solve this by putting the button in column 12.
[image]
However this only works when the browser is in fullscreen, as resizing the browser shrinks the button.
[image]

Is there any way to stretch the textfield to fill all available space (as in picture 1) without putting the button in column 12, so that the button doesn't shrink when resizing the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can do it, check the example

```css
.wrapper
{
  display: flex;
}

input {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <input />
    <button>confirm</button>
</div>
```

While `justify-content` creates space between the elements, `flex` expands the elements so they take all the space. The `flex: 1 1 auto` is the great choice for the forms like here because it doesn't change the size of the button, but the input.

Here is deeper explanation if you need:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox

and one more for even deeper understanding:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: This looks very much like what I'm after, I need to see if I can somehow use this within oracle APEX

Comment: I haven't really figured out yet how to use this in oracle APEX, but its a good answer to my question :)

Comment: @Moptan when i was reading your question there was no mentioning about APEX, sorry, can't help with it. And thank you:)

Comment: Not a problem, it was my fault alone, I did not specify APEX in my description. I only had it as a tag to the question :D